# How to get the unique regex count from a column - Oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to get the unique regex match count from a column. (I'm using Oracle DB)

```
For ex: 

table A 
Col1 Col2
1    test test test XXXX-1234 test XXXX-3456
2    test note note note XXXX-65577 test XXXX-1234
3    test note note note XXXX-9999 test test note
```

I need to get the result as `4` [here, the unique number is `1234, 3456, 65577, 9999`]

I tried using `select sum(regexp_count(Col2, 'XXXX:[0-9]')) from table A`, but it gives me the count as `6`, this includes duplicate number as well.

Kindly suggest a solution. Thanks.

Comment: In your current approach, which part of your code do you expect to recognize that a number is a duplicate ACROSS rows (not within the same row)?

Comment: Both! Duplicate numbers may be there in same row and in different row. I need to pick the unique count. @mathguy. BTW - Thanks for your answer, trying that out..

Comment: My point was that the code you tried had no way of succeeding. There is no comparison of numbers across different rows.

Comment: The query i mentioned gives the count correctly, only issue is it considers the duplicate numbers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using regular expressions:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( Col1, Col2 ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'test test test XXXX-1234 test XXXX-3456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'test note note note XXXX-65577 test XXXX-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'test note note note XXXX-9999 test test note' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH start_pos ( Col2, start_pos ) AS (
  SELECT Col2, INSTR( Col2, 'XXXX-' ) + 5
  FROM   A
  WHERE  INSTR( Col2, 'XXXX-' ) > 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT Col2, INSTR( Col2, 'XXXX-', start_pos ) + 5
  FROM   start_pos
  WHERE  INSTR( Col2, 'XXXX-', start_pos ) > 0
),
end_pos ( Col2, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT Col2, start_pos, INSTR( Col2, ' ', start_pos )
  FROM   start_pos
)
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT
         CASE end_pos
         WHEN 0 THEN SUBSTR( Col2, start_pos )
         ELSE SUBSTR( Col2, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
         END
       ) AS number_of_unique_values
FROM   end_pos;
```

**Output**:

```
                NUMBER_OF_UNIQUE_VALUES
---------------------------------------
                                      4
```

Comment: It is working fine :) Can you please explain this code, just a brief one? Where i need to add order by and group by with this query for table A's col 3 if i needed?

Comment: I have no idea why (let alone where) you would add `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` because there is no requirement for either to do what you want. Similarly, the query does not use `Col1` so having a `Col3` in the table should make no difference to it - as per `Col1` you can just ignore `Col3`.

Comment: The `start_pos` sub-query factoring clause uses recursion to iterate through each row and extract the start position of the number given by the `XXXX-` substring. Then `end_pos` finds the next space character after the `start_pos` which indicates the end of each substring. The final query just takes the substring between the start and end positions (or end-of-string if there is no following space) and counts the distinct occurrences of these strings.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to identify all the numeric fragments from each row. I use a standard approach for this, in a subquery. Then it's trivial to do a `count (distinct ....)` for the final answer.

```
with table_a ( col1, col2 ) as (
       select 1, 'test test test XXXX-1234 test XXXX-3456'       from dual union all
       select 2, 'test note note note XXXX-65577 test XXXX-1234' from dual union all
       select 3, 'test note note note XXXX-9999 test XXXX-1234'  from dual
     )
-- End of SIMULATED data (not part of the solution!) SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select count (distinct nbr) as distinct_nbr_count
from   ( select regexp_substr(col2, '\d+', 1, level) as nbr
         from   table_a
         connect by regexp_substr(col2, '\d+', 1, level) is not null
             and prior col1 = col1
             and prior sys_guid() is not null
       )
;

DISTINCT_NBR_COUNT
------------------
4
```

Comment: Million records is there in the table_A, seems it is taking too much time to complete the query. Still in progress! :/

Comment: @user3763227 - TOUGH! You have two very time-consuming operations: REGEXP_<anything> is slow and consumes a lot of CPU, and count(DISTINCT <anything>) is also notoriously slow. It is not clear how else you would do this though. If you need to run this more than once, you may want to consider a materialized view to speed up future executions.

Comment: Is there any way to pick the numbers with out regex_substr (as it takes lots of time :/) (okay, even it contains the duplicate numbers) as an array?

Comment: @user3763227 - I don't know why you think procedural code (arrays, "code logic", writing anything in PL/SQL or java or c# or whatnot) will be faster. In fact it is almost certain to be much slower still. Doing something without regular expressions - using standard string functions instead - would indeed be helpful, but I am not sure how it would work. Is it true that the numbers are always preceded by a dash ( - ) and followed by a space or the end of line, and no other strings (other than these numbers) are ever preceded by dash and followed by space or end-of-line?

Comment: Also, are you able to obtain execution statistics (limiting the search to, say, 100k rows, by adding `where rownum <= 100000` to the subquery), to see where most of the time goes? If regular expressions don't consume too much time and instead the majority of time goes to the count distinct, then I don't see any good solution (other than the materialized view approach I mentioned earlier).